# ImageMagick.NET 'Could Not Load File or Assembly'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to get set up with ImageMagick.NET with Visual Studio 2012. I've done much research into what seems to be a common issue whereby Visual Studio is not recognizing the dependencies of ImageMagick.NET (it recognizes the .NET DLL just fine judging by the auto complete). I took steps suggested in threads such as this:

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/discussions/66874

whereby the .NET DLL is referenced within the project, making sure I take note I chose the 16-numbered build, then downloading the 6.5.3-10 versioned dependencies from the following link:

http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/

which installs the DLLs and places them automatically on the system path so I shouldn't theoretically have to copy the DLL's from the install directory into my project.... but this I also have done, in several different locations, including the project root, bin, the Debug and x86 directories, etc. I also made sure I was building for x86 machines, as that seems to be the only architecture supported by the DLL. Yet despite my measures, no dice! I would greatly appreciate if someone has any further insight into why this might be happening the way it is. I'm building a C# project and trying to just initialize the project within a Windows 8 grid app template.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I apologize in not being explicit about the error message I am receiving:

Exception: Thrown: "Could not load file or assembly 'ImageMagickNET.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."

Comment: I have started a new C# library for ImageMagick called Magick.NET. It statically links with ImageMagick so you don't have to install the ImageMagick libraries separately. You can find the project here: https://magick.codeplex.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dlmestra; in the interest of time, I may not be able to utilize that solution given I have taken other means to accomplish my task, but I will most definitely take it into consideration should another project require ImageMagick on the Windows platform.